# Is it okay to contact our customers asking them for vacant jobs?

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process, resignation, united-states

So I am working with a company and I submitted my leave notice and will be leaving in couple weeks.

I am a developer and I was part of the whole application life cycle: Meeting the customers and end users, implementing, delivering and supporting. I maintained an excellent relation with my contacts and they like me a lot and think that I am very good at what I do.

Some of our customers have an IT/CS Department but I never had a contact with that department. I used to be in contact with managers and their operators within production areas and others.

I was wondering if it is okay to ask my contacts for recommending me for the available positions at their companies? And should it be done through my current company's business email or not?

**Edit:** I did not sign any contracts.

Comment: General contact will depend on your employment agreement and your relationship with the clients. 
Do NOT use your current company business email for that.  You could however use it to let them know that you are leaving.  Then, use your personal email to followup with them.

Comment: Could also be under the the terms of the contract with the client that they won't hire away any employees.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Even if it is completely legal and not against your company policy, it is incredibly unprofessional.  And there is a good chance that at least one of your customers is going to contact your current company and let them know you are soliciting them for a new job.  This could be cause for immediate termination.

That does not mean you can not ask your contacts you have made with the company about a position they have posted on their website.  But do so using your private email, and not during work hours.

Comment: Totally unprofessional

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your current employment contract. There may be a clause saying that you won't go to work for clients or suppliers for a period of time. And yes - if it's an issue, they WILL find out.

Comment: Hi please see edit.

Comment: Hmm... a down-vote because an assumption had to be made due to missing information....

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on whether you want to burn any bridges or if that's a concern for you.  If not, go for it. Especially since you've already given notice.

Bear in mind that you probably **will** be burning bridges. It could affect future recommendations or references beyond "yes, she worked here" which in itself can sometimes have a negative effect.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you would be looking to do the same thing for them as an employee as you do as an advisory/contractor/Etc. You are thus leaving your current employer who likely has an agreement, even if just verbally. You are taking away income from your previous employer. Regardless of employer policy this is not a very good move in the business world and many prospective employers will look down on it because they obviously do not want this happening to them as well.